# Access Owncloud data files stored same server from php

Tags: image, file, localhost, owncloud

I need to have access from php/html to files stored in my owncloud.org installation (same server diferent directory)

Whe I try to image display using `<img ...` I only see a box without image.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to load the image directly via a url pointing to the files location inside the owncloud file structure? owncloud will prevent this, in the end you are trying to access internal or private data via a public url. That would be a huge security flaw.

If the image is inside a users file hierarchy inside owncloud then you can access it using the "official" link, as long as it is shared by the user.

The only workaround would be to use administrative means on server level. This is of course something the owncloud software cannot prevent. If you have those rights you can create a second Directory / Location inside the http servers configuration to provide a second base url publishing those files. This would access the file system whilst bypassing the owncloud software. But take care what you are doing, those are sensitive files...